# Not hitting my controller action in SPA app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have an ASP.NET Core app with a React frontend. The following are the routes defined in my `Startup.cs`.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "default",
       template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
       name: "spa-catchall",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

I created a test action in my `HomeController` which will serve a static page but I'm not hitting it. I always end up with the `Home/Index` which is defined as the catch-all route.

This is my test action under `HomeController`:

```
[Route("test")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Test()
{
   return View();
}
```

I'm trying to hit it by going to `http://localhost:123/test` but it's not working. I also tried `http://localhost:123/home/test`. That didn't work either.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Home` controller is defined as:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("test")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

then request to `http://localhost:123/test` should hit the `Test()` action. Attribute routing has priority over conventional routing. Since you have used `Route` attribute for `Test` action, it does not matter what routes you map in `UseMvc` call, those are just not used.

The only explanation why `http://localhost:123/test` does not hit, is that you also have `Route` attribute on controller level. If it's `Route("home")` then `Test()` action could be reached by `http://localhost:123/home/test` url. If you want to keep controller level attribute, then changing route attribute for `TestAction()` from `[Route("test")]` to `[Route("/test")]` will make `http://localhost:123/test` to reach `TestAction()`.

If this still does not help, please update the question with full code of `HomeController`.

Comment: It was a stupid error on my part but I accepted your response as the answer because there are a lot of great explanations in it. I appreciate your detailed answer.